# Google Gadget API remote-content issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-gadget

In my Google Gadget JavaScript, I have an URL to call from Google Apps Script.

```
function getFileId(postData) {
  var params = {};  
  var url = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/mycompany.com/s/AAABBBCCCDDEEE-FFF-GGG/exec";
  params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.POST_DATA] = postData;
  params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.TEXT;
  params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.GET;
  gadgets.io.makeRequest(url , responseFileId, params);
};
```

So, when the function responseFileId() has returned obj.text, it actually goes to the mycompany.com login screen. That means it needs authentication from that Gadget I did. Didn't that Google Gadget hold my current domain's Google credential for running the Google Apps Script at "https://script.google.com/a/macros/mycompany.com/s/AAABBBCCCDDEEE-FFF-GGG/exec"?

I tried to run manually with Google Chrome browser, (https://script.google.com/a/macros/mycompany.com/s/AAABBBCCCDDEEE-FFF-GGG/exec) and it returns value without showing up the login screen...

Can someone tells what step has been missing for this? Has this something to do with Google OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this. I found a better idea => Using  tags for remote website.